# generate categorical dataset in python

Tags: python, random, dataset, simulation

Suppose I have a list of ten cities :

```
["paris", "barcelona", "kolkata", "new york"]
```

How can I simulate n random datasets of two attributes each having 2 cities selected from the above list:

```
["paris", "barcelona"]
["barcelona", "kolata"]
["new york", "paris"]
["paris", "barcelona"]
["new york", "paris"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`random.sample`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.sample) like this

```
data = ["paris", "barcelona", "kolkata", "new york"]
import random
print [random.sample(data, 2) for _ in xrange(5)]
```